# Proving uniform convergence on an unbounded interval

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

> Prove that the following series 
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx}{1+n^2\log^2(n)x^2}$$
>   converges uniformly on $[\epsilon,\infty)$ for any $\epsilon>0.$

What I have done:

The function 
$$f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+n^2\log^2(n)x^2}$$ is a decreasing function on $[1,\infty)$. So on $[1,\infty)$ its  maximun value is 
$$f_n(1)=\frac{n}{1+n^2\log^2(n)}\leq\frac{n}{n+n^2\log^2(n)}=\frac{1}{1+n\log^2(n)}=M_n.$$

By Cauchy Condensation Test, $\sum M_n$ is convergent. Therefore by the Weierstrass-M Test $\sum f_n(x)$ is convergent on $[1,\infty)$.

I am not entirely sure about the following statement. Please correct me if I am wrong:

> > If we can prove that the $\sum f_n(x)$ is  uniformly convergent on both $[\epsilon,1]$ and $[1,\infty)$, then it is uniformly convergent on $[\epsilon, \infty)$.

But I don't know how to prove that $\sum f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent on $[\epsilon,1]$. I need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$\left(\frac{t}{1+\log^2(n)t^2}\right)'=\frac{1-\log^2(n)t^2}{(1+\log^2(n)t^2)^2}$$
and therefore the positive function $t\to \frac{t}{1+\log^2(n)t^2}$ is increasing in $[0,\frac{1}{\log(n)}]$, and decreasing $[\frac{1}{\log(n)}, +\infty)$.
Hence, by letting $t=nx$, then $\frac{1}{\log(n)}<n\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$, and
$$\sup_{x\in [\epsilon,+\infty)}\frac{nx}{1+n^2\log^2(n)x^2}=
\sup_{t\in [n\epsilon,+\infty)}\frac{t}{1+\log^2(n)t^2}=\frac{n\epsilon}{1+\log^2(n)n^2\epsilon^2}\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon n\log^2(n)}$$
where the series $\sum \frac{1}{n\log^2(n)}$ is convergent (compare with the integral of $\frac{1}{x\log^2(x)}$). So now you can use the Weierstrass-M Test.

Comment: The sup is $a_n=\frac{1}{2\log(n)}$. But $\sum a_n$ is divergent. So we cannot use the Weirstrass-M Test.

Comment: @learning_math But your question is about absolutely (pointwise) convergence not uniform convergence. Am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have edited the question.

Comment: @learning_math I made typo. See my edited answer.

Comment: I think you mean, the function is increasing on $[0,\frac{1}{n\log(n)}]$,  not  $[0,\frac{1}{\log(n)}]$ (same thing with decreasing). Other than that the answer is great.

Comment: @learning_math Here the variable is $t$ which is equal to $nx$. So I think my answer is correct. Passing to the variable $x$, the interval $[0,\frac{1}{\log(n)}]$ becomes $[0,\frac{1}{n\log(n)}]$.

Answer (score 3):

The statement you mention is correct: the uniform convergence of a sequence 
$\left(f_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ to $f$ on a set $A$ means that $\sup_{x\in A}\left\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\right\rvert$ goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity. If the sequence is also uniformly convergent to $f$ on $B$, then use the fact that $\sup_{A\cup B}=\max\left\{\sup_A,\sup_B\right\}$ to get the uniform  convergence on $A\cup B$. Since the uniform convergence of a series is the same as the uniform convergence of the partial sums, the argument also applies to the convergence of series.

Now back to the initial problem. If $\varepsilon\leqslant x\leqslant 1$, then   $$\left\lvert  \frac{nx}{1+n^2\log^2(n)x^2}\right\rvert \leqslant\frac{n}{1+n^2\log^2(n)\varepsilon^2},              $$
and the right hand side is the general term of a convergent series.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f_n$ attains its maximum when $x=\frac1{n\log n}$, if $\frac {1}{n\log n}<\varepsilon$; its value there is $\frac1{\log n}$. Of course, if $n$ is large enough, $\frac{1}{n\log n}\leqslant\varepsilon$ and so the maximum of $f_n$ will be then $f_n(\varepsilon)$. But$$f_n(\varepsilon)=\frac{n\varepsilon}{1+n^2\log^2(n)\varepsilon^2}<\frac1{n\log^2(n)\varepsilon}.$$As you wrote, we can use the Cauchy condensation test here.